British or American English
Is the phrase “stative verb” used also in American English or only in British English?
I’ve only known it as “state of being verbs” in American English.
Thank you.

The phrase stative verb is indeed more common in BrE in the last three decades, but its use in AmE is also significant.

Thank you very much!
